# Is there a way to transition an array of nodes in JavaFX

Tags: java, animation, javafx

If I create an array of nodes can I transition each of them without creating separate transition instances for each?

```
ArrayList<ImageView> leftScoringNodeBgArray = new ArrayList();

for (int i = 0; i<5; i++){
    leftScoringNodeBgArray.add(new ImageView(leftScoringBgImage));
} 

TranslateTransition leftTransition1 = new TranslateTransition();
TranslateTransition leftTransition2 = new TranslateTransition();
TranslateTransition leftTransition3 = new TranslateTransition();
TranslateTransition leftTransition4 = new TranslateTransition();
TranslateTransition leftTransition5 = new TranslateTransition();

leftTransition1.setNode(leftScoringNodeBgArray.get(0);    
leftTransition2.setNode(leftScoringNodeBgArray.get(1);
leftTransition3.setNode(leftScoringNodeBgArray.get(2);
leftTransition4.setNode(leftScoringNodeBgArray.get(3);
leftTransition5.setNode(leftScoringNodeBgArray.get(4);

leftTransition1.setToX(300);
leftTransition2.setToX(400);
leftTransition3.setToX(500);
leftTransition4.setToX(600);
leftTransition5.setToX(700);

leftTransition1.setCycleCount(1);
leftTransition2.setCycleCount(1);
leftTransition3.setCycleCount(1);
leftTransition4.setCycleCount(1);
leftTransition5.setCycleCount(1);

SequentialTransition st = new SequentialTransition(leftTransition1, leftTransition2, leftTransition3, leftTransition4, leftTransition5);
st.play();
```

really the only thing that changes for each of these is the final X position.
Is there a way I can create all the transitions in the loop so as to avoid defining transition parameters repetitively?

Comment: What do you do after with these Transition ?

Comment: i place them in a SequentialTransition() and play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create them like this (and add them to a `SequentialTransition` ) :

```
ArrayList<ImageView> leftScoringNodeBgArray = new ArrayList<>();
SequentialTransition seq = new SequentialTransition();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    leftScoringNodeBgArray.add(new ImageView(leftScoringBgImage));

    TranslateTransition tr = new TranslateTransition();
    tr.setNode(leftScoringNodeBgArray.get(0));
    tr.setToX(300 + i * 100);
    tr.setCycleCount(1);
    seq.getChildren().add(tr);
}
```